# How to assign items to an existing Enumproperty

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, error

Im trying to assign items to an existing enumproperty already in the context.scene

```
items = []
for f in fullpath:
    item = (f.split('.')[0], f, '')
    items.append(item)

bpy.context.scene.mytool.my_enum = items
```

This is not working for me so obviously is not the way to do it.
Its need an enum not a list. Someone can help?

Comment: It's probably better to just create a new EnumProperty and then set the scene.mytool.my_enum to that, rather than trying to change the existing EnumProperty items.

Comment: You need to setup a dynamic enum property, there are plenty of Q&As about it in here